# Constraining two points, a specified distance apart, to a line

Tags: equation-solving, function-construction

Suppose that I have two points in the *xy* plane: `pt1` and `pt2init`.  `pt1` is fixed in space, while `pt2init` is supplied by the user (but its returned value will in general be different).  I wish to write a function that will return the coordinates of a point `pt2result` that is located a user-specified distance `d` from `pt1` **along the line connecting `pt1` and `pt2init`** and that is *closest* to `pt2init`.

I wrote the following function `f` (and its supporting function `dist2D`, which finds the distance between two points with x- and y-coordinates):

```
dist2D[pt1_, pt2_] := 
 Sqrt[(pt2[[1]] - pt1[[1]])^2 + (pt2[[2]] - pt1[[1]])^2]

f[pt1_, pt2_, d_] := Module[{line, x2result, y2result, pt2result},
  line = Normal[LinearModelFit[{pt1, pt2}, xvar, xvar]];
  Solve[{dist2D[{pt1[[1]], pt1[[2]]}, {x2result, y2result}] == d,
    y2result == (line /. xvar -> x2result)},
   {x2result, y2result}];
  pt2result = {x2result, y2result}
  ]
```

But when I run it:

```
f[{0.77825, 0.551441676}, {0.7075, 0.67398427}]
```

it does not return anything.  Is it possible to do constrained optimization like this?

Comment: BTW: your `dist2D[]` is built-in as `EuclideanDistance[]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Implementation

You could use a very simple function:

```
f[p1_, p2_, d_] := Normalize[p2 - p1] d + p1
```

This will return a point on the line connecting `p1` and `p2`, a distance `d` from `p1` towards `p2`.

#### Discussion

Using vector arithmetic is usually very convenient for analytic geometry.  Fortunately in Mathematica there's no need to separate the components of the vectors (e.g. writing `p1[[1]]`).  We can add two vectors directly.  `Normalize[p2-p1]` will construct the unit vector pointing from `p1` in the direction of `p2`.  Multiplying it by `d` and adding it to `p1` gives what you asked for.

#### Trying it out

```
p1 = {0, 0};
Manipulate[
 Graphics[{PointSize[0.03], Point[p1], 
   Text["\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(P\), \(1\)]\)", p1, {-2, 2}], Point[p2],
    Text["\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(P\), \(2\)]\)", p2, {-2, 2}], 
   Line[{p1, p2}], Red, Point[f[p1, p2, d]]}, 
  PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}],
 {{p2, {.5, .5}}, Locator}, {{d, 0.2}, 0, 1}
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 3):

(Too long for a comment.)

Only simple math is needed; no optimization required at all. Consider the vector equation $\mathbf x(t)=(1-t)\mathbf p_1+t\mathbf p_2$ for the line segment joining $\mathbf p_1$ and $\mathbf p_2$. The distance between $\mathbf p_1$ and $\mathbf x(t)$ is (check this!) $dt$, where $d$ is the length of the segment joining $\mathbf p_1$ and $\mathbf p_2$. You should now be able to reckon out the value of $t$ needed so that it is at a given distance from $\mathbf p_1$.